# How to bypass NameServer IpAddress?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity 2018. In My project I have to find my website address. I have used this code to find the web address.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;

public class IpAddressFind : MonoBehaviour {
    public string url="https://www.friendslearn.com";
    void Start () {
        GetIP(url);
    }

    public static string GetIP(string url) {
        url = url.Replace("http://", ""); //remove http://
        url = url.Replace("https://", ""); //remove https://
        url = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("/")); //remove everything after the first /

        try {           
            IPHostEntry hosts = Dns.GetHostEntry(url);
            Debug.Log(hosts.AddressList.Length);
            Debug.Log(hosts.HostName);

            if(hosts.AddressList.Length > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log(hosts.AddressList[0].ToString());
                Debug.Log("Final");
            }
        } catch {
            Debug.Log ("Could not get IP for URL " + url);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This returns the CloudFlare address.

Actually my website is working in amazon EC2 and I am using nameserver in CloudFlare. When I run the code it returns the CloudFlare web address. Actually my web address is 13.37.202.259. But it returns CloudFlare's IP.

How to find my EC2 address?

EDIT:I am using old code. Is there any new API to find my IP address. In Unity 2018.

Comment: Instead of all sorts of scary string replacements, [use the `Uri` object to get the host](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQd6Ul). Then; you're doing a DNS lookup for `www.friendslearn.com` which will return, naturally, the CloudFlare IP you configured in your DNS. Can you explain **why** you would want to resolve the EC2 IP? One option would be to configure another DNS entry (ec2.friendslearn.com for example) and have it point to the EC2 IP. But my gut tells me you're trying to achieve something that's not meant to be done.

Comment: I think to help we need more of what you actually are trying to achieve, as name servers are there for a purpose

Comment: you can use httpclient to archiving this https://github.com/drittich/DnsTube/blob/master/DnsTube/Utility.cs